# Are there two types of balances?

Tags: classical-mechanics, home-experiment, equilibrium

It seems to me there are two types of balances.

When you balance rocks, it seems like as you're getting closer to the equilibrium point, the stones tend less and less to fall.

But when you balance for example this spoon on the tape, it's impossible to me to find the equilibrium point and the spoon seems to move from pushing one side to the state of dominance of the force in the other direction without any intermediate state (I tried it on several similar objects and I tried to fix the spoon tight to the tape as well. Also, the objects had al).

What is the difference between these two systems and what's the official name for it?

[image: balancing spoon on a tape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about the different types of static equilibriums where a body is at rest and the net force acting on it is zero.

[image]

Imagine a ball bearing in a metal channel with a shape as in diagram $1$.
The ball bearing is static equilibrium as it is not moving the the force of gravity is by the normal reaction produced by the channel.
If the ball bearing is displaced a little the net force on the ball bearing is such that the ball bearing goes back to its static equilibrium position.
This is called stable equilibrium.

Diagram $3$ shows the ball bearing on the inverted channel again in static equilibrium.
The smallest movement of the ball bearing from that position will result in the ball bearing having a net force on it which moves it away from the static equilibrium position.
This is called unstable equilibrium and your spoon and tape system is of this type as is trying to stand a pencil on its pointed end. 
I think that you tape and spoon is this situation.

In fact all the diagrams are graph of potential energy (vertical axis) against position.

You can think of these situations in another way.
Does a small displacement cause the vertical line through the centre of mass pass through the contact area of the pivot - your tape in contact with the table and is the centre of mass or below the contact area?

You have a very small point of contact of the tape with the table and the centre of mass of your tape and spoon is above the table so a mall disturbance will the vertical line outside the contact area and because the centre of mass is above the contact area the spoon tape system will move away from the static equilibrium position.
Displacing the spoon make the potential energy of the spoon at tape decrease and so it is a diagram $3$ situation.

Bending the spoon and also adding weight to the ends will lower the centre of mass of the spoon-tape system below the point of contact makes it a diagram $1$ situation and you should be able to balance the tape and the spoon but possibly I would replace the spoon with something less valuable?

Diagram $2$ shows a position which is called neutral equilibrium where you displace the ball bearing and it stays in its new position of static equilibrium.

Diagram $4$ is called a meta stable state where the ball bearing is in static equilibrium but a push which is large enough to make it got over the right hand bump will mean that the forces on the ball bearing will be such as to go away from its original position.
You can possibly liken your pile of stones like this where a very, very small push will not disturb them but a small push will?

A good example of balance is the bird on the end of a finger which is in stable equilibrium.

[image]

Here the illusion is that the centre of mass of the bird is to the right of the beak but because of the weights in the wings it is vertically below the beak in the diagram.
So the net force on the bird is zero and it is in static equilibrium.

If the right of the bird is depressed the centre of mass of the bird moves to the left (so there is now a net force trying to move the bird back to its original position) and upwards (and so the potential energy of the bird has increased.

This is the diagram $1$ situation and so the bird moves back to where it started - stable equilibrium.

Comment: Thanks. But how to find out which one is which? (In other words I'm asking what is the difference between balancing a spoon on the margin of a cup and balancing it on the tape, just like in the other answer)

Comment: I have added to my answer and I hope it now does fully answer your question?  You need the vertical line from the centre of mass to go though the area of contact and if that area of contact is small you need to have the centre of mass below the area of contact.  For your spoon on the edge of the cup it might be that the centre of mass is below the area of contact of contact whereas your tape and spoon is obviously a situation where the centre os mass is a long way above the area of contact.

Comment: In your spoon-tape system you have two contact areas - spoon-tape and tape-table and so you need to have the stable equilibrium condition satisfied for both  the spoon and the tape other wise the tape will topple even though the spoon is stable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one corresponds to an energy minimum (a stable node) while another corresponds to an energy maximum (an unstable node). See the [classification of critical points](http://staff.www.ltu.se/~larserik/applmath/chap9en/part7.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you, but what is the difference between balancing a spoon on the margin of a cup and balancing it on the tape?

Comment: Never mind, see the upper answer, if you're interested.